# Просмотр дополнительной информации на jQuery

Tags: jquery, php

Всем доброго времени суток :) Возник очень геморный вопросик, поэтому просьба слабонервных и товарищей которые любят ставить дизлайки, дальше не читать ^^.

И так, если Вы не не нашли себя в выше перечисленном списке, тогда вопросик к вам.

**Имеется:**

1. 16-летний балбес (Тобишь я)
2. Желание воплотить игрушку детства (Покемошки ^^)

**Сам вопрос:**

У этих товарищей, покемонов, имеется такие характеристики как:

1. Статы (HP, Атака, Скорость и т.п.)
2. Атаки (То, чем они друг друга греют ^^)
3. Информация (Пол, Хозяин и т.п.)

**Задача:**

Есть такой **html** код:

```
     <center class='errorMess'>#999 Pokemon</center>        
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span id='pokeTitle'><img src='/style/pok/norm/.jpg' width='250' height='190' border='1'></span>
            <table border=0 cellspacing=0 width=252 height=10>
              <tr>
                <td style='padding:0'>
                  <div style='width:2%;background:green;height:15px;font-size:9pt;color:black;'>0</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style='padding:0'>
                  <div style='width:2%;background:blue;height:6px;font-size:0pt;'>0</div>
                </td>
              </tr> 
            </table>
            <div class='itemUse'>
              <a href='0' id='dropItemFromPok'><img src=/style/items/.gif width=32 height=32 alt='' title='' border='0'></a>
            </div>  
          </td>
          <td>
            <div style='text-align:center; font:11px Tahoma; color: #1D4141;'>
              <a href='#' id='clickInfoPok1-1'>инфо</a> -
              <a href='#' id='clickInfoPok2-1'>статы</a> -
              <a href='#' id='clickInfoPok3-1'>атаки</a> 
            </div>

            <div style='height:200;'>

              <div id='infoPok1-1'>
                <center><b>Информация</b></center>
                <img src='/style/another/0.gif' width='7' height='13' border='0'><b></b><BR>
                <b>Тип:</b> <BR>
                <b>Характер:</b> <BR>

                <p><a href='2' id='makeStart'>Сделать стартовым</a></p>
              </div>

              <div id='infoPok2-1'>
                <center><b>Статы</b></center>
                <table>
                  <td><td><i>Стат</i></td> <td><i>Ген</i></td> <td><i>EV</i></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>НР:</td> <td>0</td> <td width='30'>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Атака:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Защита:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Скорость:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Спец. Атака:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Спец. Защита:</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td><b>&nbsp;EV: 0</b></td> <td></td> <td></td></tr>
                </table>  
              </div>

              <div id='infoPok3-1'>
                <center><b>Атаки</b></center>
                <table>
                  <tr><td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                  <tr><td>0</td> <td>0</td></tr>
                </table>

                <p><center><a href='#' id='teachAtk'>Начать тренировку</a></center></p>
              </div>

            </div>
          </td>     
        </tr>
      </table>
```

`
А также, есть код на jQuery:

```
var i=1;
while(i <= 6){
  $('#infoPok1-'+i).hide();
  $('#infoPok3-'+i).hide();
  $('#clickInfoPok1-'+i).click(function(){
    $('#infoPok1-'+i).fadeIn(700);
    $('#infoPok2-'+i).hide();
    $('#infoPok3-'+i).hide();   
  });
  $('#clickInfoPok2-'+i).click(function(){
    $('#infoPok1-'+i).hide();
    $('#infoPok2-'+i).fadeIn(700);
    $('#infoPok3-'+i).hide();
  });
  $('#clickInfoPok3-'+i).click(function(){
    $('#infoPok1-'+i).hide();
    $('#infoPok2-'+i).hide();
    $('#infoPok3-'+i).fadeIn(700);  
  });  
  i++;
}
```

Вот, суть вопроса состоит в том, чтобы можно было листать характеристики покемонов.

**Объяснения:**

Такие блоки как:

1. infoPok1-1
2. infoPok2-1
3. infoPok3-1

Должны по очереди чередоваться. Например, блок `<div id='infoPok1-1'>` открытый, но
остальные же блоки должны быть закрыты. Наш `<div id='infoPok1-1'>` отвечает за информацию о покемоне. Но если пользователь захотел узнать какие статы у его питомцы, он нажимает на статы, и блок `<div id='infoPok1-1'>` закрывается, а блок `<div id='infoPok2-1'>` открывается. Буду очень благодарен тому кто поможет :)

Comment: Куча php-кода, а нужен jquery-слайдер - почитайте исходники любого или возьмите готовый. Благо, сейчас есть очень удобный сборник библиотек - http://plugins.jquery.com/ .

Comment: Скорее html кода выведенного через php ;)

Comment: `mysql` устарел, изучайте сразу `mysqli` или `PDO`.

`if($row['hp'] == 2 or $row['hp'] < 2)` - есть такой оператор "меньше или равно" `<=`, чудом превращает код в более читабельный. 

Ваша конструкция ветвлений явно имеет лишний `else`. Вполне достаточно `if {} elseif {} else {}`.

Ну а чему относится приведенный jQuery-код смотреть даже не появилось желания - лучше приведите код выводимых html-блоков и опишите проблему, но сначала всё-таки посмотрите, как пишут слайдеры.

Comment: Щас поправлю код, одну секунду :) Кстати, пробовал эту штуку "<=" У меня постоянно ошибка, может старая версия php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По  jquery, весь ваш `while` не нужен

сделайте в html

```
   <div class="menu" style='text-align:center; font:11px Tahoma; color: #1D4141;'> <a href='#' class='clickinfo' data-target='Info'>инфо</a> - <a href='#'
        class='clickinfo' data-target='Stats'>статы</a> - <a href='#' class='clickinfo'
        data-target='Attacks'>атаки</a> </div>
```

и

```
<div style='height:200;' class='info'>
    <div class='Info'>
        <center><b>Информация</b>
```

в js

```
$('.info div').hide();
$('.info .Stats').show();
$('body').on('click', '.PockemonContainer .menu > a', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.data('target');
    var show = $this.parents('.PockemonContainer').find('.info .' + target);
    $this.parents('.PockemonContainer').find('.info').children(':visible').not(show).fadeOut(100);
    show.fadeIn(100);
    return false;
});
```

[демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/CT9Hh/);

Comment: Ухты пухты)) Работает, спасибо)